# null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument in Xcode 7

Tags: ios

in Xcode 7 i got this yellow warning: 
null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument. my code is below, the fifth line is highlighted (nil part)
(mainVC.currentActiveNVC.viewControllers = nil;)
please help me. Thanks.

```
if (!mainVC.isInitialStart)
{
    CGRect openedFrame = mainVC.currentActiveNVC.view.frame;
    [mainVC.currentActiveNVC.view removeFromSuperview];
    mainVC.currentActiveNVC.viewControllers = nil;
    mainVC.currentActiveNVC = nil;

    mainVC.currentActiveNVC = destinationNVC;
    mainVC.currentActiveNVC.view.frame = openedFrame;
    navItem = destinationNVC.navigationBar.topItem;

}
```

[image]

Comment: I heard others said it is because in iOS9, it needs to make it a empty string, I tried to replace nil to "" but it doesn't work, so bad

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can pass it an empty array.

```
mainVC.currentActiveNVC.viewControllers = @[];
```

Answer (score -2):

Gooooooosh!! I found the answer. just change the "nil" to "@[]" the @[] expression is for empty string in iOS9.

Comment: @[] is an empty array, not an empty string. And it has nothing to do with iOS9, it's an ObjC language feature.